# Tightly coupled code with requireJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I have pretty rudimentary knowledge in javascript. I plan on implementing RequireJS in my application for dynamic script loading & dependency management. 
Going through an [example](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-requirejs-for-effective-javascript-module-loading/)

In the example there are 4 js files purchase.js, products.js, credits.js. main.js.

main.js initializes the flow. I understand main.js needs the `require` method.

```
require(["purchase"],function(purchase){
  purchase.purchaseProduct();
});
```

but then the every js files begins with `define()` for an instance a code snippet from purchase.js

```
define(["credits","products"], function(credits,products) {

  console.log("Function : purchaseProduct");

  return {
    purchaseProduct: function() {
```

Now as per this example say if I have `n` js files in my project & I write the code in this fashion. In future say I need to remove RequireJS from my application. I have to edit `n` js files.

Isn't this too much tight coupling of js code with requirejs library? Unlike the standard way of including js files using the `script` tag in html files.
Had I included the scripts with the script tag in the html file. I don't have to edit all the js files for any change.

Is there any other way to declare the dependencies for every js file of the project in a centralized place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Isn't this too much tight coupling of js code with requirejs library?

What you show in your question does not indicate tight coupling with *RequireJS*. You are using the AMD spec to declare your modules and loading them. The only thing this entails is that you need to have a module loader which is compatible with AMD. This could be RequireJS, or it could be [Almond](https://github.com/jrburke/almond) or it could be Node.js with the [node-amd-loader](https://github.com/ajaxorg/node-amd-loader) package. And I believe there are even more options available.

> Is there any other way to declare the dependencies for every js file of the project in a centralized place?

If you do not want the `define` calls to appear in each of your files, and still *preserve the modularity* of your code, and have the dependencies all located in a "centralized place", RequireJS does not have built-in support for this. You might be able to hijack the `shim` configuration option for this purpose but I don't see this being a simple matter. The `shim` setting is pretty much a crutch that allows using non-modular code with RequireJS and it relies on symbols being available on the global space, this goes against the goal of preserving modularity. Otherwise, you could design a build process that would read a file and on the basis of this file build each source file into a proper AMD module by wrapping the code into a `define` call.

Comment: Anyway if in future I plan to implement any other library I need to change the code in all the js files right?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "implement any other library".

Comment: Say rather than RequireJS I want to use labJS or Browserify in future, I again would have to change the code in all the js files

Comment: It depends on how you design the build process I've mentioned at the end of the last paragraph. You can make informed decisions about how the build process will work so as to avoid problems that can be *reasonably foreseen* but there is no guarantee ever that switching to a new script loader won't have a ripple effect that will need changing all the files. I'm not familiar with labJS so I don't know what this particular switch would entail.

Answer (score 2):

When using any kind of module-loading system, tight coupling is often not avoidable.

In the case of requirejs it luckily is, but requires a little more initial work per file:

```
function myModule(dependency1, dependency2) {
  //usual code
}

if (typeof define !== "undefined") {
  define(["dependency1", "dependency2"], myModule);
} else {
  myModule(dependency1, dependency2)
}
```

Comment: How on earth does this help the OP with the goal of "declar[ing] the dependencies for every js file of the project in a centralized place"?